# JADE works below or over HTTP?

Tags: http, agents-jade

I was working on Java Agent Development Framework, which is the language of creating mobile agents. I was wondering that the code that I will write in JADE, will work over HTTP or below the HTTP? As I am opaque to the inside working and execution of JADE I couldn't get the answer directly...Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I think most people here are talking about Jade the nodejs templating language :-) http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: yeah! that's the tragedy :-( No one i guess knows about http://jade.tilab.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JADE (or more generally FIPA standard) introduces the concept of platform consisting of one or more containers on which agents live. Each container is made up by a separate JVM. JADE distinguishes between two types of communication, depending on where the talking agents live:

- **intra-platform communication**, when messages are exchanged between agents living on different containers of the same plaform
- **inter-platform communication**, when messages are exchanged between agents living in different platforms

Depending on where the talking agents live, different protocol will be used.

For intra-platform communication one of the following transport protocols will be used:

- RMI (default), going directly over TCP/IP
- proprietary protocol based on TCP sockets (used in J2ME environment in JADE LEAP platform)

For inter-platform communication one of the following transport protocols will be used:

- IIOP (Sun or ORBacus implementation)
- HTTP and HTTPS
- JMS
- Jabber XMPP

Since the question is specific to JADE platform, I strongly encourage you to use JADE mailing list: http://jade.tilab.com/newuser.php